# what is causing my Wildfly BOM compile error

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, wildfly-21

I am upgrading to wildfly 21.0.2.Final for an application and wanted to pull the BOM for it rather than linking the dependencies that I needed 1 at a time.

mvnrepository says it should look like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly/wildfly-feature-pack -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-feature-pack</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, when I attempt to package that using `mvn clean package` i get these errors:

Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:test:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: `org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.6-RC1`, `org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:jar:1.2.6-RC1`, `org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-compat:jar:1.2.6-RC1`: Could not find artifact org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.6-RC1 in central (https://companyNameglobal.jfrog.io/companyNameglobal/maven-all)

It appears as if the artifacts don't exist, but then why would they be required in the wildfly BOM?

Any help would be great.

Comment: BOM stands for Byte Order Mark?  Do you mean POM?

Comment: The BOM stands for bill of materials... See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms First in the example is that a bom is not used as a dependency it should be used via a import scope instead see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies

Comment: You likely shouldn't be using the feature pack as a BOM. There is a `org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools:21.0.2.FInal` that would probably be a better option.